# How do I always serve the same file with express?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

Is there any way I can always serve the same file?

So, if they go to website.com/ajsdflkasjd it still serves the same file as website.com/asdnw

I would like to do this using express with node.

The file I have is a static html file, not a jade file.

By the way, the reason I'm wanting to do this, in case you were wondering, is I have an angularjs app that handles all the routing for me. So, all I need to do is serve that one page, and it will take care of the rest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## new answer

```
const app= require('express')()
     // static file serve
     app.use(express.static(__dirname))
     // not found in static files, so default to index.html
     app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`))
app.listen(3000)
```

## old answer

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
     // url encoding
     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
     // gzip
     // redirect all html requests to `index.html`
     app.use(function (req, res, next) {
         if (path.extname(req.path).length > 0) {
                 // normal static file request
                 next();
             }
         else {
                 // should force return `index.html` for angular.js
                 req.url = '/index.html';
                 next();
             }
     });
     // static file serve
     app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: A year and a half later, but this is a great answer. Just check if it is an asset by the filename extension. This is *so* much simpler than my original implementation. Thanks Zane!

Comment: @Merc This is probably not how I would do this now, just so you know...I mean, it works, but I would probably just serve the static files first, and then send the index file, if the file weren't in there...I'll update my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Below is what I'm using express with angularjs in my project. It will always send `index.html` unless the browser requests resource files (images, css, js, etc.) which contains extname.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    app.configure(function () {
        // url encoding
        app.use(express.urlencoded());
        // gzip
        app.use(express.compress());
        // redirect all html requests to `index.html`
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            if (path.extname(req.path).length > 0) {
                // normal static file request
                next();
            }
            else {
                // should force return `index.html` for angular.js
                req.url = '/index.html';
                next();
            }
        });
        // static file serve
        app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    });
```

Comment: Duuuude, thank you so much, that's perfect! Unfortunately, express has deprecated some of the stuff in that code though, so here's the updated version for the latest version of express, I'll just put it an answer

Answer (score 1):

Basic configuration for Express 4 is:

```
var express = require('express');

express()
    .get(/.*/, function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile('index.html', {
            root: __dirname
        });
    })
    .listen(8080);
```

[Working example](http://runnable.com/VS9sHzxKiysOyaYr/basic-express-4-configuration-for-single-page-apps-for-node-js-and-hello-world)

Those snippets with GZip, BodyParser etc. are pretty cool, but I think over-complicated if you want to just test your single page app. Of course you can add all this "production stuff" when it starts to be needed.

Read more:

- [sending files](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile)
- [routing](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple implementation with ExpressJs to create a virtual host and whenever return the index.html

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var vhost = require('vhost');

// Function to create virtualhost
function createVhost(domain,rootDirectory){
  var exp = express();
  exp.use(express.static(rootDirectory));
  exp.get(/.*/,function(req,res){
    res.sendFile('index.html',{root:rootDirectory});
})
app.use(vhost(domain,exp));
}

// Virtual Host to create
createVhost('example.com','/home/[user]/[www]/[example.com]');
createVhost('othersite.com','/home/[user]/[www]/[othersite.com]');

// Start Server
app.listen(80,function(){
  console.log('Node server on port 80');
});
```

Remember:

Add the domains in the "/etc/host" (in linux)

```
127.0.0.1  example.com
127.0.0.1  othersite.com
```

And run in the terminal the "app.js" with "sudo" for port 80

```
~/home/[server]$ sudo node app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in both angular as well as node side.

In Node side you can do something like this:

```
res.sendfile('<ur html file path');
```

In Angular if you using ui-router you can make use of

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/otherwise');
```

and this otherwise state needs to be defined as well

```
$stateProvider
.state("otherwise", { url : '/urPage'...})
```

If you using ngRoute, you can do

```
 $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/urPage'});
```

**UPDATE**

Since your routers are not configured to show a default urPage, in the server you can have something as:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.get('/urPage',function(req,res){
  res.sendfile('<ur html page>');
});
```

Comment: Well, that's not really what I'm trying to do...

What I meant was how do I do the part

`app.get('/[<--this part]',function(req,res){res.sendFile('index.html')})`

How do I make that a regular expression or something that catches all traffic and redirects it to that html page

Comment: you can make use of app.all and inside check the regex you want to and then send the file