# 404 Not Found page - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I uploaded my site on server and my site works fine. but I have a problem.

when I go to route `A` from route `B`, `B` component loaded as well. but when I copy my `B` component url I got `404 Not Found page`.

for example when I copy/paste this url:

http://test.shadyab.com/offers/Arya-Ceremonial-Pool-VIP-off

I got a `404 Not Found page`.

my route:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import configureStore from 'store/configureStore'

import App from 'containers/App'
import Home from 'containers/Home'
import Detail from 'containers/Detail'
import Cart from 'containers/Cart'
import Login from 'containers/Login'
import Profile from 'containers/Profile'
import Category from 'containers/Category'

export default function(history) {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route exact path="/offers/:id" component={Detail} />
        <Route path="/cart/cart" component={Cart} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/profile/:section" component={Profile} />
        <Route path="/category/:city/:category" component={Category} />
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

my `app.js`:

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

import configureStore from 'store/configureStore'
import createRoutes from 'routes/index'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import _ from 'lodash'

let reduxState = {}
if (window.__REDUX_STATE__) {
  try {
    let plain = JSON.parse(unescape(__REDUX_STATE__))
    _.each(plain, (val, key)=> {
      reduxState[key] = Immutable.fromJS(val)
    })
  } catch (e) {
  }
}

const store = configureStore(reduxState)

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    { createRoutes(browserHistory) }
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Even if the user wants to refresh the current webpage, he will receive a 404 error.

my server language is php.

Comment: You need to redirect all urls to index.html for it to work

Comment: Even if the user wants to refresh the webpage, he will receive a 404 error.

Comment: Because of the same thing as before.

Comment: Here is simple article to fix this issue. We can solve this issue for any SPA framework https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/14/how-to-fix-404-page-not-found-error-after-build-in-angular-or-react-or-vue-js/

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure your server to always serve your `index.html` file for all urls.

Here is one of the example how to do it in NodeJS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25374786/3187014

Answer (score -1):

.htaccess file resolves same problem for me:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www from host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Don't rewrite files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31391039)